# How to cast string to number in angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a select box from which I am binding the selected value to `startingYear` variable. I want type of startingYear to be in number. But its always in string.

How can I cast it to number?

```js
console.log(StartingYear);
```

```html
<select  [(ngModel)]="StartingYear">  
    <option *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
                      {{i}}
     </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha check **console.log(typeof(this.StartingYear))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` property would be a string by default, so use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#ngValue) property to the option tag. Unlike the value binding, ngValue supports binding to objects.

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="StartingYear">  
  <option *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4]; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">
        {{i}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @NareshShetty can you share the component typescript file, what's the type of `StartingYear`  ?